# PHP IntelliJ does not find usages of function calls. Finds usages of class though

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm

I'm searching for usages of my class

```
namespace bar;
class Foo{

 public static function baz(){
 }
}
```

and IDE finds tons of references. But IDE cannot find usages of the call `Foo::baz()` even though there are many references.

Am I missing something?

Comment: works for me (PhpStorm 10.0.3)

Comment: Works fine. Please try standard for such cases `File | Invalidate Caches...` and restart IDE.

Comment: Intellij-IDEA or PHPStorm ? Is not the same...

Comment: i'm having the same issue- seems to have started happening ever since i switched to namespace based projects whereas before i was not using namespaces